# JSONStore + adapter pushing replace - how to give _id as a parameter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I've been testing and learning to use the JSONStore in combination with an MobileFirst SQL Adapter. Everything is working fine but I can't find a solution for the next obstacle.

When I edit an item in a JSONStore collection via replace it works fine locally. When I push the collection it gets to the adapter correctly. The problem is I have no way to tell the database which record to update. This way it just updates all record to the given information.

Collection that is inited:

```
caller.open = function(){
WL.JSONStore.destroy();

var collections = {
    people: {
        searchFields: {
            name: 'string',
            age: 'integer'},
        //-- Start adapter metadata
        adapter : {
            name: 'test',
            add: 'addTest',
            remove: 'deleteTest',
            replace: 'updateTest',
            load: {
                procedure: 'getTests',
                params: [],
                key: 'peopleList'
            }
        }
        //-- End adapter metadata
        }
    };

    //Initialize
    WL.JSONStore.init(collections)
        .then(function () {
            WL.Logger.debug("succes open");
            caller.sync();
            //handle success
        })
        .fail(function (errorObject) {
            WL.Logger.debug("failed open");
            //handle failure
        });
}
```

Edit method that is called (with pushrequest and push for testing purposes):

```
caller.edit = function(){
var document = {_id: 3, json: {name: 'joopy', age: 666}};
var collectionName = 'people';
var options = {}; //default
WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName)
    .replace(document, options)
    .then(function () {
        //handle success
        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).getPushRequired()
        .then(function (results) {
            WL.Logger.debug(results);
            WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).push()
            .then(function (res) {
            //handle success
            //res is an empty array if all documents reached the server
                //res is an array of error responses if some documents failed to reach the server
            })
            .fail(function (errorObject) {
            //handle failure
            });
        //handle success
        })
        .fail(function (errorObject) {
        //handle failure
        });
    })
    .fail(function (errorObject) {
        //handle failure
    });
}
```

The following is the adapter method this is called correctly but it needs a way to specify a certain record in the database.

```
function updateTest(data) {

//WL.Logger.error('Got data from JSONStore to REPLACE: ' + data);

var object = JSON.parse(data);  

return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : updateStatement,
    parameters : [object.name, object.age]
});
}
```

Using the currently commented WL.Logger.error shows this information:

**[ERROR   ] Got data from JSONStore to REPLACE: {"name":"joopy","age":666} [project MyFirstApp]**

What I need is, either a way for data to also give me the old data or the _id, or another parameter with information that can be used to specify the record in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Working with external data](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html) part of the documentation. Basically, instead of `WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).push()` you can do:

```
var accessor = WL.JSONStore.get('people');

accessor.getAllDirty()

.then(function (dirtyDocs) {
  // ...
});
```

The `dirtyDocs` argument looks like the following example:

```
[{_id: 1,
  json: {id: 1, ssn: '111-22-3333', name: 'Carlos'},
  _operation: 'add',
  _dirty: '1395774961,12902'}]
```

> What I need is, either a way for data to also give me the old data or the _id, or another parameter with information that can be used to specify the record in the database.

You will have `_id`, then you can do:

```
.then(function (dirtyDocs) {

  return WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
    adapter : 'people',
    procedure : 'updatePeople',
    parameters : [ dirtyDocs ]
  });
})
```